# File upload through sendkeys() fail due to input type=file not visible on webpage

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, sendkeys

I am trying to upload file using `sendkeys()`
but selenium webdriver test fails with error:

```
"The element is not yet visible: By.xpath: //input[@id='upload-file-pc']"
```

Here is the html:

```
<input id="upload-file-pc" class="file-field-input" type="file" onchange="return validateFileSelected(this);" name="upload-file-pc"/>
<a class="dropbox-dropin-btn dropbox-dropin-default file-field-link" href="Javascript:void(0);">
<span class="dropin-btn-status"/>
Choose from Computer
</a>
```

Code:

```
    String fileLocation = CommonConstants.TEST_FILE_LOCATION + this.config.getString("simpletext");
        logger.info("text file location: {}", fileLocation);
        WebExecutionHelper.waitForElementVisible(driver, By.xpath("//input[@type='file']")).sendKeys(fileLocation);
```

Upload Button Image:
[image]

**Please help**

Comment: Can you add the code how did you try

Comment: Added code in description

Comment: The `<input>` won't accept text. `sendkeys()` may not work.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium probably doesn't operate on hidden elements. What you can do is force it to appear with `executeScript`:

```
// get <input> element
input = driver.findElementById("upload-file-pc")

// make it visible
driver.executeScript(`
    var input = arguments[0];
    input.className = '';
    input.style.display = 'block';
    input.style.position = 'fixed';
    input.style.bottom = 0;
    input.style.left = 0;
    `, input)

// set the file
input.sendKeys(fileLocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

Selenium can't operate (e.g sendKeys, click) on invisible element.

You can send the uploaded file's absolute path in backgroud by executeScript.

Java example:

```
    WebElement fileUpload = driver.findElement(By.css("#upload-file-pc"));
    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    js.executeScript("return arguments[0].value=arguments[1];", fileUpload);
```